# Spring-batch-admin integration with current application

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am getting following error, while trying to integrate Spring-batch admin in my already existing application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter@39db61fa] with key 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter@39db61fa] with key 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:609)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:534)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:662)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:599)
    ... 32 more
```

P.S I have a job configuration existing in my application which I removed and tried deploying the application on tomcat 7 yet I get the same error. I read on this link that its due to trying to deploy two job configuration applications on same server.

Following is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Newer version of apache datasource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring batch admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSql DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

If you guys need any other information will provide that.

Comment: What version of Spring Batch Admin and other related libraries are you using?

Comment: How are you bootstrapping Spring Batch Admin?